# Manga with three characters given magical items so they can collect badges

Tags: story-identification, manga, sword-and-sorcery

What I remember is there’s three main characters two boys one girl and they all decide to join a competition in Japan. Eventually the government delivers them weapons that best suit them. The red haired male character gets a void lion claw, the black haired male got a demonic katana he can’t unsheathe at first and the female gets a crystal that allows her to heal her comrades.

Eventually they’re given a mission to collect badges from other players which leads them to be being chased by a giant dragon while driving a car to escape. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How long ago did you read this manga? And if you can,  in which website.

Comment: What's a void lion?

Comment: Or, different modifier association context, what's a "lion claw" as a weapon?

Comment: I've noticed that you've dumped this question onto a bunch of different platforms over a matter of months, all with identical details. I've also noticed that although you've been asked (repeatedly) for extra details, you've declined to respond. If you engage with us and answer some questions about the property, you're far more likely to get an answer than if you just "hit and run".

Comment: So the void lion claw is what the manga called the weapon but the weapon in real life is called aTekko-kagi. And the last time I read this manga was quite awhile ago on mangafox. I’m sorry if it’s a little vague explanation I’m trying to remember more details as I go

Comment: Just putting the external cross-post in case it's answered on there: https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/f6mt3t/cant_remember_the_name_of_this_manga_help/